# Как преобразовать формат 'time' в число

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица sql, колонка имеет формат 'time'.
Запись содержит значение 00:03:01, и я передаю его в переменную.
Как мне получить количество секунд из этой переменной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В *PHP* есть классы *DateTime* (http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php), *DateInterval* (http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php) и еще несколько других, которые позволяют произвести большинство необходимых операций со временем и датами.

В Вашем случае подойдет что-то типа:

```
$dt = new DateTime('00:03:01');
echo (int)$dt->format('s'); // выводим отформатированную дату, показывая только секунды, и преобразуем в целое число
```

Comment: Нужна сумма секунд, т.е. 181

Comment: Так сделайте по аналогии:
`(int)$dt->format('s') + 60 * (int)$dt->format('i') + 3600 * (int)$dt->format('H');`

Comment: Gino Pane, спасибо